# SDWebImage causing slow image binding

Tags: ios, iphone, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` to cache my images. Overall it looks good but when I use `setImageWithUrl` method, it take a bit longer to bind the image back to my `collection view`. Is there a solution to this problem? I tried the following, but looks like it's still having the same problem.

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = pictureImageView;
    [pictureImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picture.attachment.url] placeholderImage:nil options:0 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        weakImageView.image = image;
    }];
```

Comment: Not an exact solution, but you may try other more modern image caching libs, e.g. https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage.